# Combining two lists with similar elements

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

I have multiple lists each containing words and the a number representing the number of times the word showed up in a article.  I want to combine these lists together keeping unique words separate and adding the counts of same words.  Example:

```
list_one = [(u'he':3),(u'she':2),(u'it':1),(u'pineapple':1)]
list_two = [(u'he':4),(u'she':1),(u'it':0)]
```

and then by combining list_one and list_two return a list_three

```
list_three = [(u'he':7),(u'she':3),(u'it':1),(u'pineapple':1)]
```

I got lists using collections.Counter from articles and have tried using Counter.update to add the two together .  I would like to keep the order, meaning keeping the highest number of counts in the front of the list.  Any help would be great.

Swiss

Comment: That's not a valid Python data structure. Did you mix up `{}` and `()`?

Answer (score 1):

Python Counters can actually be summed! - http://ideone.com/spJMsx

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements.
>
> <sup>[From the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update)</sup>

So this:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = Counter(['eggs','spam','spam','eggs','sausage','and spam'])
list2 = Counter(['spam','bacon','spam','eggs','sausage','and spam'])

print list1
print list2
print list1+list2
```

Outputs this:

```
Counter({'eggs': 2, 'spam': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'and spam': 1})
Counter({'spam': 2, 'eggs': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'sausage': 1, 'and spam': 1})
Counter({'spam': 4, 'eggs': 3, 'sausage': 2, 'and spam': 2, 'bacon': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your two lists, adapted slightly to work in Python:

```
list_one = [(u'he', 3),(u'she', 2),(u'it', 1),(u'pineapple', 1)]
list_two = [(u'he', 4),(u'she', 1),(u'it',0)]
```

Now, let's combine them:

```
d = {word:value for word, value in list_one}
for word, value in list_two:
    d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + value
print(d)
```

This produces the desired numbers in dictionary form:

```
{u'it': 1, u'pineapple': 1, u'she': 3, u'he': 7}
```

The above is a dictionary.  If you wanted it back in list of tuple form, just use `list(d.items())`:

```
[(u'it', 1), (u'pineapple', 1), (u'she', 3), (u'he', 7)]
```